# Workaround to access library from host /usr/local/lib in Flatpak

Tags: debian, flatpak

We are trying to make a flatpak app for a set of compiled binaries. Some of the compiled binaries are using `dlopen()` call  to access libraries from the `/usr/local/lib` directory.

But unfortunately, flatpak is not exposing the `/usr/local/lib` directory as-is to the sandbox. It is instead exposed as `/var/run/host/usr/local/lib` in flatpak. In our case changing the `dlopen()` code to this mapped path is not possible as it is a third party tool making the calls.

Is it possible to refer in the sandbox to `/usr/local/lib` as it is with any workaround? We tried with `--filesytem` option, but it didn't work.

Comment: I really don't know much about these things, but perhaps you can (while in the sandbox) create a symbolic/soft link (`sudo ln -s /var/run/host/usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib`). I would expect this to break a lot of things though, as surely flatpak has a reason why they mount it at `/var/run/host` in the first place.